# Declaring a dependency in gradle on another... sourceSet?

Tags: gradle, quarkus, kotlin-multiplatform

I am trying to get started with Kotlin Multiplatform and I'm hitting a snag. The generated starter project uses ktor as the backend library, but I'd prefer to use Quarkus. The problem I'm running into is trying to make the quarkus module depend on the shared module. So here's the simplified structure (which I hope makes sense):

```
/
-/composeApp
--/androidMain
--/commonMain
--/desktopMain
-/shared
--/androidMain/kotlin
--/commonMain/kotlin
--/jvmMain/kotlin
-/quarkus
--/src/main/kotlin
```

If I add `implementation(projects.shared)` to `quarkus/build.gradle.kts`, I get this error at build time:

```
> Cannot invoke "io.quarkus.bootstrap.workspace.ArtifactSources.getSourceDirs()" 
because the return value of "io.quarkus.bootstrap.workspace.WorkspaceModule$Mutable.getSources(String)" 
is null
```

I'm not a Gradle user, but it seems to me that I need to specify *which* sourceSet unders `shared`, but, for example, `composeApp/build.gradle.kts` specifies the dependency the same way, so I'm guessing the Quarkus plugin is to blame. I'm just not sure how to fix that. Anyone? :P

Comment: When you import a dependency, Gradle uses [variant-aware matching](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/variant_model.html) to pick the right _artifact_ from the exporting project using the attributes of the consuming configuration (which in your example is `implementation`). `implementation`, as a regular Java configuration, is set up for that so your dependency is ready to use if it were a regular Java or Kotlin project. You would also get an error if there was no attribute match. Instead, Quarkus may need something different (eg maybe there's a Quarkus configuration for this purpose).

Comment: Yeah, and it's the how part that gets me. :P